# One of the Wordpress Custom Post displaying out of order

Tags: php, wordpress

I am facing a very strange problem, all my posts are displaying in proper order but one post is not following the order. Here is the picture of dashboard side:

[image]

You can see in the picture **Chapter 3** is displaying in the correct order.
Now that's the picture on the front end:

[image]

In the dropdown you can see **Chapter 3 Gases** is displaying in last while it should display after chapter 2. I'm not getting what's the problem Here is my PHP code for dropdown:

```
 <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
        <?php 
            $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'subject' );
                if ( !empty( $terms ) ){
                // get the first term
                $term = array_shift( $terms );
                // echo $term->name;
            }
            $classes = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'class' );
                if ( !empty( $classes ) ){
                // get the first term
                $class = array_shift( $classes );
                // echo $term->name;
            }
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'lecture',
                'posts_per_page'=> -1,
                'orderby' => 'date',
                'order' => 'ASC',
                'tax_query' => array(
                        'relation' => 'AND',
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'class',
                            'field'    => 'slug',
                            'terms'    => $class,
                            ),
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'subject',
                            'field'    => 'slug',
                            'terms'    => $term,
                        ),
                    )
                ); 

                $data = new WP_QUERY($args);
                $unique_chapter = array();
                while($data->have_posts()):
                $data->the_post();
                $chapter_obj = get_field('chapter');
                if( ! in_array( $chapter_obj, $unique_chapter ) ) :
                // add city to array so it doesn't repeat
                $unique_chapter[] = $chapter_obj;
                ?>
                <li><a href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>">
                    <div class="text-left chapter_heading_topnav"><?php  echo substr($chapter_obj->post_title,0,9) ;?></div>
                    <div class="text-left chapter_text_topnav"><?php  echo $chapter_obj->post_content ;?></div>
                    </a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>

    </ul>
```

As you can see I'm setting order on date bases in ascending all other chapters are displaying properly only chapter 3 is out order. Please any clue why it's happening I'll be very thankful to you for your kind help.

Comment: what is the published data for chapter 3 and 4?

Comment: change `orderby` to `menu_order` in your `$args`, should work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I fix it now actually it was displaying at the end because of the time difference all other chapter's 1st lecture was published in January while chapter 3 1st lecture was published yesterday that's why it was coming at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I checked your site, it seems to be okay now. :)

[image]

Comment: yeah, I fix it now. Actually, data was displaying on the basis of the 1st lecture of each chapter all other chapter's 1st lecture was published in January while chapter 3 1st lecture was published yesterday that's why it was displaying at the end.